# Cocoapods error : unable to update after adding new Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
- `Bolts (= 1.1)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Bolts (~> 1.1)` required by `FBSDKCoreKit (4.1.0)`
- `Bolts (~> 1.1)` required by `FBSDKCoreKit/arc (4.1.0)`
```

I'm getting following message when I was trying to add new Facebook iOS SDK 4.0. I've already added Facebook iOS SDK previous version.

How to solve it? I want to keep my pod up-to-date.

Comment: Does `pod update` help? If not then delete the `Pods` folder, the `Podfile.lock` and the `<your project>.xcworkspace` and use `pod install` to perform a clean reinstall of all pods.

Comment: Ok sure, I've not run `pod update` yet. Instead I was running `pod install` and end with above message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fluidsonic, comment works! I run `pod update` command it was stuck for some time but then worked! Everything is now up-to-date.

Comment: OK, that worked for me, too. However, I'm trying to build with Xcode Server. So, I'd prefer to use "pod install", so that it uses the Podfile.lock file that has been tested with. If I use "pod update" then it will be pulling down updated pods that I may not have tested with.